# Numpy array: Conditional encoding

Tags: encoding, scikit-learn, label

I have following numpy array:

```
array([1, 1, 1, 3, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 0, 1, 1, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3, 1, 1, 1, 1,
       1, 3, 1, 1, 3, 0, 1, 3, 1, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 2, 0, 1, 2, 0, 2,
       2, 2, 1, 2, 2, 0, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 3, 1, 1, 1, 3, 0, 2, 1, 1,
       1, 1, 3, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 2, 3,
       2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 3, 1, 0])
```

Question: How can I create another array that encodes the data, given condition: If value = 3 or 2, then "1", else "0".

I tried:

```
from sklearn.preprocessing import label_binarize
label_binarize(doc_topics, classes=[3,2])[:15]

array([[0, 0],
       [0, 0],
       [0, 0],
       [1, 0],
       [0, 0],
       [0, 0],
       [0, 0],
       [0, 0],
       [0, 0],
       [0, 0],
       [0, 1],
       [0, 0],
       [0, 0],
       [0, 0],
       [0, 1]])
```

However, this seems to return a 2-D array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`np.where`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.14.0/reference/generated/numpy.where.html) and pass your condition to mask the elements of interest to set where the condition is met to `1`, `0` otherwise:

```
In[18]:
a = np.where((a==3) | (a == 2),1,0)
a

Out[18]: 
array([0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0,
       0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1,
       0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0,
       1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0,
       0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0])
```

Here we compare the array with the desired values, and use the unary `|` to `or` the conditions, due to operator precedence we have to use parentheses `()` around the conditions.

To do this using sklearn:

```
In[68]:
binarizer = preprocessing.Binarizer(threshold=1)
binarizer.transform(a.reshape(1,-1))

Out[68]: 
array([[0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0,
        0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1,
        0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0,
        1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0,
        0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0]])
```

This treats values above `1` as `1` and `0` otherwise, this only works for this specific data set as you want `2` and `3` to be `1`, it won't work if you have other values, so the `numpy` method is more general

Comment: Thank you, that seems to work. Do you know whether there is also a scikit answer to this?

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. And good to know, because I need to select topics 11 and 42 in my true model..